# How do I override gf with vim-rails

Tags: vim

I've written a Vimscript function - `CoffeeScriptIncludeExpr` - that when assigned to `includeexpr`, allows me to use `gf` to open a CoffeeScript file when the cursor is on its classname.

However, this doesn't work in a Rails project. My vimrc contains the following

```
autocmd User Rails.javascript.coffee* set includeexpr=CoffeeScriptIncludeExpr()
autocmd User Rails.javascript.coffee* set path=app/assets/javascripts/**
```

which I had hoped would have the desired effect.

If I type `gf` in a CoffeeScript file with the cursor on `FooBar`, vim prints an error message stating `Can't find file 'foo_bar.rb' in path`. Puzzlingly, typing `set includexpr?` shows it's set to `CoffeeScriptIncludeExpr`. Similarly for `set path?`. But the error message suggests vim-rails is running the show.

What do I need to do to get `gf` to work with my CoffeeScript files?

Comment: I would have added the tag vim-rails but had insufficient rep.

Comment: Does vim-rails override the `gf` command? Find out with `:verbose nmap gf`. If it does, try unmapping with `:nunmap <buffer> gf`.

Comment: @IngoKarkat that worked, many thanks. I added an autocmd to do the unmapping.

Comment: Ah great, so my hunch was right. I've added a proper answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like *vim-rails* overrides the `gf` command; find out with `:verbose nmap gf`.

To undo this, remove the mapping with:

```
:autocmd User Rails.javascript.coffee* nunmap <buffer> gf
```