# How do I unmap only when a mapping exists in Vim

Tags: vim

As a follow-on to the accepted answer in [How do I override gf with vim-rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15430440/how-do-i-override-gf-with-vim-rails), editing the same file multiple times results in the following error:

```
Error detected while processing User Auto commands for "Rails.javascript.coffee*":
E31 : No such mapping
```

The offending line in my `vimrc` is

```
:autocmd User Rails.javascript.coffee* nunmap <buffer> gf
```

How can I avoid this error by unmapping only if the mapping already exists?

(Note: Editing the same file multiple times may seem like a strange thing to do, but I believe it happens as a side effect of searching with ack.vim or ag.vim)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You could check for the mapping with `if ! empty(maparg('gf', 'n')) ...`, but the usual solution is to just suppress the error by prepending `silent!` before the `nunmap <buffer> gf` command.